# Nodejs redis delete set of KEYS by prefix with redis-delete-wildcard is not working

Tags: node.js, redis

i'm using redis-delete-wildcard to delete keys that start with a specific prefix.

The client is:

```
const client = redis.createClient({
  port: 6379,
  host: '127.0.0.1',
})

module.exports = client
```

Here is the code:

```
var redis = require('redis');
require('redis-delete-wildcard')(redis);
const client = require('../../config/init_redis')

updatePassword: async (req, res, next) => {   
try {
  const resRef = await verifyRefreshToken(req);
  const body = req.body;
  body.userId = resRef.userId;   
  const salt = genSaltSync(10);
  body.password = hashSync(body.password, salt);
  updatePassword(body, (err, results) => {
    if (err) {
      return next(err)
    }  
    if (!results) {
      return next(createError.BadRequest('Record Not Found'))
    }
    console.log(resRef.userId) // 2
    client.delwild(resRef.userId+':*', (error, numberDeletedKeys) =>{
      if(error){
        console.log(error)
      }
      return res.json({
        status: "200",
        message: "Updated successfully"
      });
    });      
  });
} catch (error) {
  next(error)
} 
},
```

The console.log(error) is:

```
ReplyError: ERR unknown command 'eval'
    at parseError (C:\Users\tiger\Desktop\prova\REST_API_WITH_MYSQL-master\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:179:12)
    at parseType (C:\Users\tiger\Desktop\prova\REST_API_WITH_MYSQL-master\node_modules\redis-parser\lib\parser.js:302:14) {
  command: 'EVAL',
  args: [
    "local keysToDelete = redis.call('keys', ARGV[1]) if unpack(keysToDelete) ~= nil then return redis.call('del', unpack(keysToDelete)) else return 0 end ",       
    0,
    '2:*'
  ],
  code: 'ERR'
```

But when i see the keys, these are still saved:

[image]

I don't know why the delwild function is not working...what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please change the `console.log` in the callback of `client.delwild` to log both `error` and `numberDeletedKeys` and share it here?

Comment: @LeibaleEidelman sorry,you were right, I have modified just now, thank you for your reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Redis server does not recognize the ["EVAL" command](https://redis.io/commands/eval). Could be because the version is less than 2.6.0, or that the EVAL command was [renamed/disabled](https://redis.io/topics/security#disabling-of-specific-commands).